# Retrieve value of custom meta box page

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-boxes

I have added a custom meta box, once i update the data, it saved successfully. But now i am trying to fetch using this code, but it is not getting content of meta box saved. Please help me out.

```
 <?php
         global $post;
         $code = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'caption_code_footer', true ); 
         if($code != ''){
            echo $code;   
    } 
        else { ?>
         I am lorem Ipusm Text
    <?  } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code appears okey, so you need debug a bit....It's sound like $post->ID has wrong value... try echo it. `echo $post->id;` or all the object `var_dump($post);`

Also Check If you arent in right context. For example in category context you need to use [the loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)...

Comment: Hi, i am using this on page

Comment: It's better to use ``$post = get_post();`` instead of ``global $post;``

Comment: i tried as you suggest, it shows me right id on echo.

Comment: $post = get_post(); still no differance

Comment: Are you sure ``'caption_code_footer'`` is the right key? What is the result of ``var_dump($code);``?

Comment: this is the part of code: <input type="text" name="caption_code_footer" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_post_meta( $object->ID, 'caption_code_footer', true ) ); ?>" size="30" style="width:90%;" />

Answer (score 0):

I think something error on update your meta box please try this..

```
$footer=$_POST['caption_code_footer'];
update_post_meta($post_id,'caption_code_footer',$footer);
```

for echo the value updated..

```
get_post_meta($post->ID, 'caption_code_footer', true);
```